# googleVis does not work in R Notebooks

Tags: r, googlevis, sankey-diagram

I want to create sankey diagram using googleVis in R Noteboooks and knit it to HTML. However, it is not working. It does not show the sankey diagram. How to fix it? I have attached the output below the code below.

````
   ```{r}
 library(googleVis)

datSK <- data.frame(From=c(rep("A",3), rep("B", 3)),
                To=c(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"),2)),
                Weight=c(5,7,6,2,9,4))

Sankey <- gvisSankey(datSK, from="From", to="To", weight="Weight",
                 options=list(
                   sankey="{link: {color: { fill: '#d799ae' } },
                        node: { color: { fill: '#a61d4c' },
                        label: { color: '#871b47' } }}"))
 plot(Sankey)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Are you viewing the HTML file in the default RStudio viewer that pops up? I have sometimes had issues viewing these kinds of plots in the RStudio viewer, but when I open the HTML file in a browser (Chrome/Firefox) the plot displays correctly.

Comment: Even in chrome, I have the same problem.